# Python : uploading with Selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I have the following HTML in localhost :

```
<html><body><h1>test</h1>
<input type="file" id="file" />
</body></html>
```

This code works fine with Firefox webdriver, but doesn't using Chrome one:

```
dr = webdriver.Chrome()
dr.get('http://localhost')
input = dr.find_element_by_id("file")
input.send_keys("/tmp/var/test.zip")
```

I'm using Selenium 2.25

Comment: This question has nothing to do with uploading, it's just sending keys to a field... also, this code is clearly not a full example; `input` is never created, just referenced.  Do you mean to have `input=dr.find_element ...` somewhere?

Comment: I'm using a similar code(with Ext.js) to test an upload input and works fine in Firefox, as I said above. 

input is created with dr.find_element_by_id('file'), my mistake

Comment: So exactly what error are you getting?

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u'Element is not clickable at point (-422, 314)'

Comment: Does your script also click on something?  A submit button or something perhaps?

Comment: only the submit button, but in Chrome the script doesn't reach to that part, before failing to do the send_keys